# Load a movie on a sprite as3

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, away3d

I'm working on a project with away3DLite on AS3, and I'm trying to put a video inside, I already have the square where the video is going to be displayed but for me to put the video there I need to put it as a material, anto create a material with video the cosntructor asks for the movie in a sprite, here are the docs " http://away3d.com/livedocs/lite_1.0.2_lib/away3dlite/materials/MovieMaterial.html ".
All I need is to load the viedeo on a sprite to create the material.

But how do I load a video on a sprite?

Comment: MovieClip inherits from Sprite so you should be able to typecast to it. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but anyone needing a Netstream based video player for Away3D Lite feel free to use my [VideoMaterial](https://github.com/wemakedotcoms/Away3D/blob/master/com/wemakedotcoms/away3DLite/VideoMaterial.as)

Comment: Welcome to ! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm working on a framework built over the Away3dLite framework, and the version of away3D used for that is and old one which does not include the MovieMaterial class, also I don´t have source code of my framework to change the version of away3D.
And I don´t know if there's another way to include that class in my project.

Comment: MovieMaterial extends BitmapMaterial. You could simply add a version of the MovieMaterial class along with the VideoMaterial to your current code, just update the import paths.